# DocumentDB - DELETE causes 401 error

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I always get 401 when I try to execute a DELETE verb against a DocumentDB collection. POST for queries/inserts/updates works fine, so I am sure that my code that calculates the authorization token is correct. What I am not sure however is what I should pass for the resource id and resource type.

```
payLoad := LowerCase(Verb) + #10+
           LowerCase(resourceType) + #10+
           LowerCase(resourceId) + #10+
           LowerCase(utc_date) + #10 +
           '' + #10; //instead of the "date" header
```

For the POST (which works), I use

```
"docs" and "dbs/mydb/mycol/licenses"
```

For DELETE I use the value of the "_self" property for the url of the doc to be deleted. I tried just about any combination of resource type and resource id I could think of:

```
docs    dbs/icUoAA==/colls/icUoAKizCgA=/docs
docs    dbs/icUoAA==/colls/icUoAKizCgA=/docs/icUoAKizCgADAAAAAAAAAA==
docs    dbs/icUoAA==/colls/icUoAKizCgA=/docs/icUoAKizCgADAAAAAAAAAA==/
docs/icUoAKizCgADAAAAAAAAAA==   dbs/icUoAA==/colls/icUoAKizCgA=/docs
docs/icUoAKizCgADAAAAAAAAAA==   dbs/icUoAA==/colls/icUoAKizCgA=/docs/icUoAKizCgADAAAAAAAAAA==
etc.
```

DELETE however always fails with 401. Do I need to use something different?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the `Delete Document REST API` documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt489087.aspx, I noticed that it expects the document name instead of system assigned resource id while you're using the resource id. Could that be the reason for this error you're getting?

Comment: But what is "name"? It is definitely not an id (there were quite a few discussions where people complain that you cannot use id for a deletion), so it can be either "_self" or "_rid".

Comment: From the examples I have seen, my take is that "name" is the "id" that you assign to the document in your collection.

Comment: I don't think you can delete by an id - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333050-it-should-be-possible-to-remove-a-document-by-id - you still need a selflink

Comment: Have you read this post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/? Or is it just SDK thing and not available at the REST API level?

Comment: Yes, but I read it that it is only available on the .Net SDK level and the libraries for other languages. If I use a url with an id (e.g. 'dbs/mydb/colls/mycol/docs /cc0d4caabc714aac976c9d0a2e9243ed'), I get back 400 error - {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Request url is invalid.\r\nActivityId: 91f46993-6bbe-4d5a-a130-6825df212263"}.

Comment: Sorry, there was a space in the url above - if I remove it, i still get 401

Comment: The documentation for calculating authorization header states that the resource id should be used as is and should not be converted to lower case (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn783368.aspx), which I believe you're doing (based on your code above). I'm surprised that how your other requests are working in this case.

Comment: But would only matter if I use a selflink - my ids and db names are all lower case.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko : I remember having similar issues with deleting a db - I do not remember on top of my head but here is a link to my doc db rest endpoint playbook sort where I put in a few lines of code to save myself some time for future reference https://github.com/jayalakshmis/IDIOSYNCRASIES/tree/master/DocDb%20-%20REST%20API%20Playbook  - this might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two kinds of requests you can make to DocumentDB. One is based on the "id" property that you define, and one based on the internal resource id ("_rid"). When you're using "id", you need to use the entire link for generating the authorization token, so for delete it would look like

```
delete
docs
dbs/mydb/colls/mycol/docs/cc0d4caabc714aac976c9d0a2e9243ed
sun, 21 aug 2016 20:00:00
 //newline
```

If you're using the internal resource ID, then you just pass in the "_rid" of the document you're trying to delete, for example

```
delete
docs
icuoakizcgadaaaaaaaaaa== //lowercase
sun, 21 aug 2016 20:00:00
 //newline
```

One thing which might help debugging these is looking at the response body that's returned with the 401. It should contain an error message telling you the payload that the server expected.

Comment: Also, you should be able to delete documents using "id" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt489087.aspx