# DocumentDB: Can't access documents in my collection

Tags: rest, azure, postman, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using DocumentDB, and want to access via REST-API a specific `document` from one of my `collections` with a submitted query.

I want to test the call with Postman. I configured the headers and the authentication-token, and everything works as expected (for example I'm able to get a list of all of my `collections`), but I can't read the `documents`.

I'm calling the following URI:

```
POST https://xxx.azure.com/dbs/testDB/colls/offer/docs
```

Authorization Token is generated with the following parameters:

```
verb: "POST"
resourceType: "docs"
resourceID: "dbs/testDB/colls/offer"
x-ms-date: ...
masterkey: "P8riQ...aMORA=="
```

Headers are:

```
x-ms-documentdb-isquery: True
x-ms-date: ...
authorization: generated token
x-ms-version: 2015-08-06
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Body is (x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
query: SELECT * FROM offer
parameters: []
```

But the response from Postman is always:

```
{
  "code": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\ndocs\ndbs/testDB/colls/offer\nfri, 30 sep 2016 13:47:32 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: a76408d...e08cef"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have misused the Rest API. If you are attempting to [Querying Offers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt489062.aspx), the POST uri should be like with `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/offers`.

And if you are attempting to [Query Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt670897.aspx) (which may actually be the one you want to achieve). The POST uri should be `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs`

Please try to follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt670897.aspx to impelemnt the Rest API to query documents.

## update

And try to generate Authorization token with:

```
verb: "POST"
resourceType: "docs"
resourceID: "dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}"
x-ms-date: ...
masterkey: "P8riQ...aMORA=="
```

I used the code snippet in this answer of [DocumentDB REST API with Postman outputs always "Unauthorized" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768732/documentdb-rest-api-with-postman-outputs-always-unauthorized-error),

```
getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey("POST", "docs", "dbs/testdb/colls/offer", headers, "{key}"));
```

to generate the authorization token. And worked fine on PostMan:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But what is the difference? I can just spot the missing "docs" at the end of my resourceID, but even with that it does not work :/ If I try your first hint, so the short URL, I get an error "Request url is invalid"

Comment: Each DocumentDB collection is provisioned with an associated performance level represented as an **Offer**.  For detailed info between offer and docs, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt632095.aspx & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt489082.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I think my question got misunderstood. My collection-name is "offer". I also have collections which are named like "products", "shops" etc. So please imagine the same described problem with the `resourceID: dbs/testDB/colls/products/docs` and the `URL https://xxx.documents.azure.com/dbs/testDB/colls/products/docs`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your scenario, and I was able to successfully query documents using Postman.

To help you troubleshoot, here are the parameters I used to compute the token (including a dummy key so you can try as well):

- Auth Token Parameters:

  ```
  verb: "POST"
  resourceId: "dbs/testDB/colls/offer"
  resourceType: "docs"
  key: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmn=="
  keyType: "master"
  tokenVersion: "1.0
  date: "Thu, 06 Oct 2016 04:31:33 GMT"
  ```
- The resulting token is:

  ```
  type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3dC373dEIadokxR4z%2bSSpmbpVYw4e7mk9Vhae%2f5nLaD%2bU%3d
  ```
- Request verb and URI

  ```
  POST https://xxx.documents.azure.com/dbs/testDB/colls/offer/docs
  ```
- Headers:

  ```
  authorization: type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3dC373dEIadokxR4z%2bSSpmbpVYw4e7mk9Vhae%2f5nLaD%2bU%3d
  x-ms-date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016 04:31:33 GMT
  x-ms-version: 2015-08-06
  x-ms-documentdb-isquery: true
  Content-Type: application/query+json
  ```
- Body:

  ```
  {"query":"SELECT * FROM c"}
  ```

Notice I used a different Content-Type from the one you are using. I don't think this is what's causing your issue, since you would get a Bad Request response if that were the problem.

To summarize, I believe the issue is within your token generator, since I used the same parameters as you to generate the token, and the same URI for the POST request.

I am posting a dummy masterkey, date, and resulting token so you can use it to test your token generator. Hope this help to narrow down the source of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this a bit frustrating to get working too, so I created a blog post that takes you through it - using powershell to build the calls, but the process and format of the strings is the important piece.  I had issues with the date formatting, and what strings to use to identify the resources you need to query.

Take a look at [Managing DocumentDB with powershell](https://russellyoung.net/2016/06/18/managing-documentdb-with-powershell/) - I found the error messages were fairly important, check the inputs you create vs the detail in the output error message.

Comment: Thank you. I made the same steps as your blog-post recommends, and I'm able to retrieve all documents in a specific collection, or all databases, but I'm unable to POST a query in order to get a specific range of documents, because the response is always ""unauthorized" (please check my question, I don't know if I am doing something wrong with ResoureID and ResourceType).

Comment: You should use GET to retrieve documents, but POST to update/insert (that's the REST way - relies on HTTP Verbs for defining how the function behaves and what it does)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using POST as verb and the right resourceID "dbs/testDB/colls/offer" (please check my question), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, missed the point - I thought you were just trying to get the list of documents, which doesn't need you to use the query engine.  Ive been through it visually and cant see anything obvious that would stop the authentication piece working, and if it works for Gets the one thing I think may be wrong is that you have the verb input to your key ('POST') in upper case, it needs to be lower - when the key gets encrypted this will make a difference.  Did you try that?

Comment: Thank you, yes I tried that, my verb is automatically converted to lowercase. GET is working properly (for listing all documents), but the same call with POST and a query in body (and the verb POST) is resulting in an "unauthorized" error. Pretty weird.