# 401 error for deleting user defined function with documentdb nodejs client

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I am able to successfully call `readStoredProcedure`, but with the same link, not for `deleteUserDefinedFunction` --- I tried variations of the link (`_self`, or generating the Uri with `UriFactory.createStoredProcedureUri`) --- again, they all work with read and execute, but *not* for delete.  The full error message being

```
The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign:...
```

I looked at the source code and the two functions (read and delete) seem to be using the path in the same way.

I am aware of the question [DocumentDB - DELETE causes 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067048/documentdb-delete-causes-401-error), but it's for document deletion issues and does not seem to fix the UDF issue I run into

Might anyone know what's going on?

Thanks so much!

Here is how I am calling it just for reference:

```
let sprocUri = documentdb.UriFactory.createStoredProcedureUri(DATABASEID,COLLECTIONID, name);
console.log("sprcURI", sprocUri);
client.readStoredProcedure(sprocUri, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
       console.log("bad", JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {
        console.log(`Succes for temporal queries: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        client.deleteUserDefinedFunction(sprocUri, ResponseLoggingWrapper("DELETE sproc " + name));
    }
});
```

Note that I have replaced the 2nd use of `sprocUri` with `response._self` as well but to no avail.

Also note that I am using Stored Procedures but it's mostly the same as UDFs behavior-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`deleteStoredProcedure`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/7df00c6b7b0f7dc192c609b4329136ba9c704f5c/source/lib/documentclient.js#L1270) function to delete a stored procedure.

> [image]